# Copy a file into a created directory

Tags: c#, winforms, file-io

I'm working on a project where I want  a directory to be generated according to a textfield value and   I want to copy a file into the created folder...So far I could able to create the directory and copy the file but into the created folder....

```
try
{
    string id = textBox4.Text.Trim();
    // Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\prashan\\Desktop\\"+id);
    string source = null;                 

    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

    if (ofd.ShowDialog()==System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
    {
        source = ofd.FileName;
        MessageBox.Show(source);
    }

    string File_name = Path.GetFileName(source);

    string destination = "C:\\Users\\prashan\\Desktop\\" +
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(id) + File_name;

    System.IO.File.Copy(source, destination);
    MessageBox.Show("Done....");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem? I don't see any actual question in your post..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following code:

```
string destination = "C:\\Users\\prashan\\Desktop\\" 
    + System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(id) + File_name;
```

You are concatenating the result of CreateDirectory() into your destination filename, which is incorrect. Instead, you could split this into two operations, like this:

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\prashan\\Desktop\\" + id);
string destination = "C:\\Users\\prashan\\Desktop\\" + id + "\\" + File_name;
```

This isn't the cleanest way to do this, using Path.Combine() would be better, but I wanted to change your code as little as possible.

Comment: But I think it's the full path, not the single directory name isn't it? Possibly `destination = Path.Combine(System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\prashan\\Desktop\\" + id), File_name)` would have been a better example.

Comment: Yes, that'd be the best. But I doubt that was a fullpath, since MSDN says "original path", and in the code above that's `id = textbox.Text`. I sense short name, not full path, but that's all just guessing. My point in the first comment was just that CreateDirectory()'s result is concatenatable to a path, so I think you could make the `incorrect` a little softer.

Answer (score 0):

Small change in your code. Destination path modified to make it valid path.

```
try
        {
            string id = textBox4.Text.Trim(); 
            Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\\Users\\prashan\\Desktop\\"+id);
            string source = null;
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                source = ofd.FileName;
                MessageBox.Show(source);

            }

            string File_name = Path.GetFileName(source);

            string destination = "C:\\Users\\prashan\\Desktop\\" + id +"\\"+ File_name;


            System.IO.File.Copy(source, destination);
            MessageBox.Show("Done....");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks.Description added.